# How to extract seconds from time string in Java?

Tags: java, string

In Java, I'd like to extract seconds from time input strings of format  like :

```
05h23m45s
```

How can I do so?

Comment: A simple regex can solve this, or even simpler String manipulation methods: simply find the number between 'm' and 's', no?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. I appreciate if you could be more specific

Comment: Look up the String API and check out the methods available. They're names are pretty self-explanatory, and then try them out. You'll gain much by trying first before asking.

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: oops, "their names" not "they're names"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's your time format, just get the substring that starts right after the `m` in minutes.

```
String time = "05h23m45s";
String seconds = time.substring(time.lastIndexOf("m") + 1, time.lastIndexOf("s"));
```

This code will return a `String` containing all the characters after the `m` and until the `s`.

I strongly suggest you to read the [String class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). The gimmicks it has are really useful when used right.

Comment: Great, just how can I eliminate 's' from the end of substring?

Comment: Rather than eliminating it, let's just avoid getting it. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

If you'd like a really robust solution for dealing with dates and times, you can consider using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) or other [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) packages (`java.text`).

```
String time = "05h23m45s";

DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh'h'mm'm'ss's'");
DateTime parsed = dateFormatter.parseDateTime(time);
int sec = parsed.getSecondOfMinute();
```

**Original answer:**

To get the seconds as an `int` value:

```
String time = "05h23m45s";
String strSeconds = time.substring(time.lastIndexOf("m") + 1, time.lastIndexOf("s"));
int seconds = Integer.parseInt(strSeconds);
System.out.println(seconds);
```

Prints out:

```
45
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String timeStr = "05h23m45s";

int sec = Integer.parseInt(timeStr.substring(6,7));
```

Amoungst many other ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("05h23m45s".split("m")[1].toString().substring(0,2));
```